# When removing a View from render, it's background continues there on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having a serious problem with React Native on Android.

Let's say I have the following render method:

```
render() {
    let stuff = this.state.showStuff ? <Text style={styles.stuff}>Stuff</Text> : null

    return (
        <View>
            { stuff }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Really simple. If I want to hide the "Stuff", I just call:

```
this.setState({ showStuff: false })
```

This works fine on iOS, but on Android, if styles.stuff define a backgroundColor, the component will be re-rendered without the "stuff" content, but with it's background!

Now I have no idea on how to remove elements from my component, since this weird behavior broke how I used to think react native works.

Comment: Weird, after removing react-native-searchbar from my component, it worked as intended.. I'm just starting to think using react-native for this project was a terrible idea

Comment: so your problem has been solved ?

Comment: Yeah. It's weird, after removing react-native-searchbar it fixed two non-related bugs on my project. Although I have no idea how it was causing them

Answer (score 0):

I found out that react-native-searchbar was causing the issue on non-related views. Removing that component solved this and other non-related issues on my project.